# convert 32 bit big endian signed integer to signed little endian integer

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, endianness

I had some unsigned 32 bit big-endian integers that I needed to convert, and that was trivially easy once I found the right header:

```
#include <endian.h>
...
be32toh(some_int);
```

However, `endian.h` specifies these are for unsigned integers. For a signed integer, I'm not really sure what to do, as it doesn't look like there are header files for this sort of thing, and I'm not really familiar with bit manipulation in C++.

Edit: Since there is some confusion about the format of my integer, let me explain more. I have an integer in the form

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz012345
```

where each character represents a bit. the `a` bit represents the sign. I know that bytes are always big endian, so in addition to moving the bytes into a different order, like

```
yz012345qrstwx...
```

I also need some way to make sure that the `y` bit shows the sign, not just some bit in the number. I ... have no idea how to do that.

Edit: my problem was that I was thinking that the sign bit was always first in order, when that is not the case. The sign bit is always the MSB, meaning that if you're in little-endian form, the sign bit is going to be in the middle of the bytes that make up your integer.

Comment: Doing things like `((x >> 24) & 0xff)` and then recombining the bytes in a different order is a valid way to convert byte order for unsigned integers. It also works for signed integers, except for the left shift which I believe is formally undefined when the integer is negative. So I think it is better to first cast to unsigned, if for no other reason than to care about future maintainers.

Comment: I think your external link (using bit-shifts on the `s32val`) is actually implicitly treating the 32-bit quantity as unsigned. Even if the bit-shifts are doing sign extension, when combined with the bit-masks, they don't result in more than byte-reversing the four bytes of an unsigned integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to byte-reverse a *signed* integer doesn't sound like it's a well-defined arithmetic operation, because the most significant bit behaves as an indicator of the sign of the integer, and it wouldn't make much sense to move that elsewhere when manipulating an integer variable.

More likely, you may have sequence of 4 bytes that represent a 32-bit signed integer, but need to be byte-reversed in order to translate between different CPU endiannesses. To do that, you can simply treat the quantities as though they were unsigned, and let `be32toh()` do the work for you:

```
(int)be32toh((unsigned)some_int);
```

or, slightly safer:

```
(int32_t)be32toh((uint32_t)some_int);
```

This works because the casting operations, when applied to integers of the same bit-depth, effectively leaves the in-memory representations unchanged. This ignores the significance of the sign (and any subtleties related to the twos-complement representation of signed integers) while doing the byte-reversal. I'm not sure that this behaviour is guaranteed by the C standard (a question for language lawyers, perhaps), but it's likely to be a very common behaviour. The description at [www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/) indicates that provided your system uses twos-complement representation for its signed integers (which is very common) then the signed-to-unsigned conversion in `(uint32_t)some_int` will do the right thing. However, the precise interpretation of the signed-to-unsigned conversion in `(int32_t)be32toh(...)` is, strictly, implementation dependent. So, again, I think the question of what it would mean to byte-reverse a *signed* integer isn't mathematically unambiguous.

Comment: can you explain why I am able to treat the quantities as though they were unsigned?

Comment: I've added more detail in the answer to try to explain why the casting (usually) works.

Answer (score 2):

This only makes sense if the native system is little endian, because what would be the point of converting data to signed little-endian on a big-endian system?

So on a little-endian system, all you need to do is cast the big-endian integer to unsigned, convert it using `be32toh`, and then cast the result to signed integer. Actually, it's better to represent the big-endian as unsigned from the start, because its sign has no meaning in a little-endian system. So, just convert the unsigned bits, and then cast to signed.

Comment: That's correct, the system is little endian natively. I just want to confirm, your answer is basically saying that rwp is correct, right?

Comment: Yes, I didn't see his answer before I posted mine. I have upvoted rwp's answer. Not sure if my vote is visible however, my reputation is still below the threshold :)

Comment: Does casting in this context change the bits in the number itself or just how c++ interprets the number? I edited my post, does that make my question more clear?

Comment: Your question is crystal clear in my opinion. And casting does not change the bits. Caveat: I'm not sure if the language spec is unambigious about this, but C (and thus C++) has a long history where it is expected that signed/unsigned only concern semantics, not data representation and storage formats. And just for reference: the ancestor of C was a language named BCPL which had the "machine word" as its one and only datatype.